# Как подключить заголовочный файл в VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Я хотел подключить свой заголовочный файл, но при сборке появляется ошибка, что такого файла или директории нет.

> EQ.h: No such file or directory gcc

В IncludePath я добавил две строки

```
"${workspaceFolder}",
"${workspaceFolder}/Headers"
```

Файл tasks.json

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe сборка активного файла",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "-IHeaders"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Задача создана отладчиком."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

}

Структура проекта и прочее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `IncludePath` влияет только на подсказки в IDE. Как вы запускаете gcc, какой-то системой сборки? Нужно ему добавить флаг `-IHeaders`.

Comment: Точно не знаю, согласно инструкции на сайте Microsoft установил MinGW и всё запускал через него. Если необходимо, то могу прикрепить файл tasks.json

Comment: Да, прикрепите. Куда вы нажимаете, чтобы запустить таску из tasks.json?

Comment: Прикрепил. Терминал->Запуск задачи->g++.exe сборка активного файла(компилятор:C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe)

Comment: Угу, значит в `"args": [...]` надо добавить `"-IHeaders"`.

Comment: Ошибка, к сожалению, никуда не делась.

Comment: Покажите новый tasks.json, лог сборки, содержимое папки `Headers`, содержимое корня проекта...

Comment: Прикрепил скриншоты и новый tasks.json

Comment: `"options": {"cwd": "${fileDirname}"},` - лишняя.

Comment: Сборка проходит успешно, если не использую что-либо из "EQ.h". Также не могу собрать "EQ.cpp"

Comment: Вы зря скопипастили себе откуда-то `tasks.json`, не разобравшись в содержимом. `"${file}"` - это имя текущего файла. Вместо него должно сработать `"Sources/helloworld.cpp", "Sources/EQ.cpp"`, но вообще уже пора (когда стало >1 файла в программе) настроить себе нормальную систему сборки, чтобы пересобирались только измененные файлы. Из популярных - Make, CMake, Meson... И из `tasks.json` вызывать уже эту систему сборки.

Comment: tasks.json был автоматически сгенерирован. Спасибо за Ваше внимание, уделенное моей проблеме, и совет